# Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset in Rest call

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, websocket, connection-pooling

I am calling REST service and one of the APIs fail intermittently, I had looked for the answer, but did not find anything significant. Below is the stacktrace.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://api.blahblah.com/v2/authentication": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:579)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735)
```

Not sure if this is because of connection pooling or anything else, Below is how I create my `restTemplate`:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setMaxConnTotal(connectionConfiguration.getMaxConnection()) //max total connections
        .setConnectionReuseStrategy(DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE) //connection reuse strategy
        .useSystemProperties() //provides the default properties which are probably not bad
        .build();


HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory connectionfactory = new  HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
connectionfactory.setReadTimeout(connectionConfiguration.getReadTimeout()); //socket read timeout fails if server doesn't respond
connectionfactory.setConnectTimeout(connectionConfiguration.getConnectionTimeout()); //timeout if the http connection cannot be established (socket failure, bubbles up as I/O error)
connectionfactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(connectionConfiguration.getConnectionTimeout()); //fails if a connection cannot be obtained from the factory

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
```

This is how I am making rest call:

```
ResponseEntity<Map> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Map.class);
```

Comment: is this api working ? `https://api.blahblah.com/v2/authentication`

Comment: @Hemant yes, it works from postman

Comment: @NisargPatil I am also facing the same issue, did you find an answer?